# How can i display capture image taken by custom camera(surfaceview) in another activity imageview in android

Tags: android, image, camera

I am developing one application. In that am displaying images taken by custom camera. I want to display picture taken by custom camera will be display in another activity imageview. am displaying picture taken by custom camera will be saved in sdcard. After image storing in sdcard move to another activity in that time am able to displaying picture taken by custom camera will be displayed in another activity imageview. first image will be displayed in imageview of another activity but next picture taken by camera that image does not shown in next activity imageview last image will be displayed. how can i refresh every time i will take the picture from camera.  how can i do this help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the getting data into a bitmap and set to imageview

https://github.com/vishnupriyanp/CustomCameraSample (See comment github)

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.am converting image into bitmap and then adding it to imageview. am edited my question see once

Comment: Check the Sdcard if the captured images are existing or not.
log the bundle data "imagepath" in different cases.

Comment: Images are displayed in sdcard. When open app and first time capture image that will be displayed in next activity imageview. but after capture first time next time capture it does not change the image. first time captured image is there in next activity imageview. how can i refresh previous image.

Comment: What about the Log ?? "bundle data "imagepath" in different cases"